# Python open html files but do not know how to save as with a different name

Tags: python, html

Im trying to open a template, modified and save it with a different name. I have done it with csv but never with html.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
with open('filename.csv', 'r') as infile, open('new_filename.csv'), 'w') as outfile:
        stripped = (line.strip() for line in infile)
        lines = (line.split(";") for line in stripped if line)
        writer = csv.writer(outfile)
        writer.writerows(lines)
```

My script in HTML is:

```
f = open('filename.html','wb')

message= """<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>My code</p></body>
</html>"""

f.write(message)
f.close()
```

It can I put in the last code save outfile as? or is there another better and useful way to do it? 
Thank you for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example on how to a html file and write it on other file:

input.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body><p>My code</p></body>
</html>
```

process_html.py:

```
def process_html(inhtml):
  # Change this function for different processing method!
  processed_html = inhtml.replace('My code', 'My Beautiful codes')
  return processed_html

with open('input.html', 'r') as infile, open('output.html', 'w') as outfile:
  inhtml = infile.read()
  processed_html = process_html(inhtml)
  outfile.write(processed_html)
```

After running process_html.py, you can expect to get an html file called `output.html` that comes from `input.html` and processed.

Comment: Thnk you, is what i was looking for!